# how to change the color of a selected MAT-SELECT option

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can't manage to change the style once an option of the MAT-SELECT of angular material is selected.

I need to do something similar to the JIRA status selector, like this:
[JIRA IMG EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tnvx.png)

I have this:
[My Component Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch1rS.png)

but when I select an option it appears without styles:
[My Component without styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0dSv.png)

HTML:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Option</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
            <mat-option value="option1"><app-badge></app-badge></mat-option>
            <mat-option value="option1"><app-badge-warning></app-badge-warning></mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
::ng-deep {


    // TEXT COLOR WHEN OPTION IS SELECTED
    .mat-mdc-option.mdc-list-item--selected:not(.mdc-list-item--disabled) .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
        // color: var(--mat-option-selected-state-label-text-color);
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    }

    
    // ARROW COLOR (Check)
    .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked.mat-pseudo-checkbox-minimal::after, .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-pseudo-checkbox-minimal::after {
        color: #000000 !important;
    }

    // COLOR WHEN AN OPTION IS SELECTED AND DISPLAYED IN SELECT
    .mat-mdc-select-value-text {
        background-color: #000000 !important;
    }

    // .mat-mdc-select-value {
    //     background-color: #000000 !important;
    // }

}
```

Example Online: https://6540fe3db9c208092603c801--comfy-lollipop-a183d1.netlify.app/

I have this version of scss but it doesn't work either:

```
::ng-deep {

    // TEXT COLOR WHEN OPTION IS SELECTED
    .mat-mdc-option.mdc-list-item--selected:not(.mdc-list-item--disabled) .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
        // color: var(--mat-option-selected-state-label-text-color);
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    }


    // ARROW COLOR (Check)
    .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked.mat-pseudo-checkbox-minimal::after,
    .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-pseudo-checkbox-minimal::after {
        color: #000000 !important;
    }

    // COLOR WHEN AN OPTION IS SELECTED AND DISPLAYED IN SELECT
    .mat-mdc-select, .mat-mdc-select-value, .mat-mdc-select-value-text {
        // background-color: #000000 !important;

        // Apply the class to the `<div>` tag containing the custom component
        ::content>.app-badge {
            display: inline-flex !important;
            padding: 2px 12px 2px 8px;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 6px;

            // cursor: pointer;

            border-radius: 6px !important;
            background: var(--transparent-success-16, rgba(54, 179, 126, 0.16)) !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this stackblitz that does something very similar to what I want to do but I'm not sure how to do it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hewot8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.scss

Answer (score 0):

I took the working stackblitz sample you provided and updated it to use the latest Angular (v16.2) thinking it could be a compatibility issue with whichever version your using. However, it's still working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e3tnvc?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Instead of using ng::deep, add the relevant styles to your global style (see 'global_styles.scss' in the stackblitz).

Then, also add a 'theme.scss' global file (again, see stackblitz). It is necessary to include a theme file to see the complete styling for Angular Material components. Make sure it is included in your **angular.json** and restart the server.

```
        "styles": [
          "src/global_styles.scss",
          "src/theme.scss"
        ],
```

Alternatively, you can include a theme by simply importing at the top of your global stylesheet, for example:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```